# Unsafe parameterized ArrayList cast after notify from Observable

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

I have a problem with the implementation of an update in the obersver pattern in JAVA.
I send an ArrayList coming from my Queueing system to my Observer/s. The problem now is in the Observer where i receive the ArrayList as an Object. The next step would be a cast into an ArrayList but due to the runtime of Java I have no parameter information, which results in a unsafe cast. I mean i could notify my Observer with a whole generic class but i dont know if I am mistaken or it is "shooting with boulders on small birds". In result there is no error in the end cause I always notify this observer with ONE typ but the question is should I take the warning or is there a workaround.

```
            ArrayList<Message> messageList = sqsUtil.getMessagefromAnotherEntrypoint("myQueueName");
        if (messageList != null) {
            // notify Observers
            notifyObservers(messageList);

        }
```

And then the the Update where the unsafe cast happens

```
    @Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    ArrayList<Message> aMessageList = (ArrayList<Message>)arg;

}
```

Nevertheless thanks for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JLS §5.1.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9) talks about unchecked casts and when/why they happen. Long story short:

- You don't check that `arg` is actually an `ArrayList` (i.e. `arg instanceof ArrayList<?>`).
- There's no possible way to check if `arg` is an `ArrayList` that contains `Message` objects (at least not without using `instanceof` on each of the elements in the `ArrayList`). In other words, `arg instanceof ArrayList<Message>` doesn't compile.

If you want to get rid of the warning (i.e. you know it won't throw an exception or you want it to if it does) then you can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Message> aMessageList = (ArrayList<Message>) arg;
}
```

If you need to get only the messages and you don't want exceptions:

```
@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    if (arg instanceof ArrayList<?>)
        for (Object o : (ArrayList<?>) arg)
            if (o instanceof Message)
                messages.add((Message) o);

    // Do stuff with the messages list
}
```

This will get only the `Message` objects from `arg` if it's an `ArrayList`, otherwise it will be empty.